# Remove top navigation bar from top and make it on left side in magento 2

Tags: extensions, navigation, magento-2.1.2

I want to remove top navigation bar from top and make it on left side in magento 2 also my directory structure is this as in image . could any one suggest any plugin or total step by step coding. I'm having a hard time finding a solution to this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on your theme.  As I'm new to this as well, and just learned magento in the past month, I've found it relies heavily on what theme you have installed, and what adjustments they have made to the base theme (blank, or luma).  You can find instructions on making a custom theme in the documentation.

Your "frontend" folder with "Magento" in it, will need a folder with "Yourtheme" in it" to start you off.  From there, adding your theme is a matter of following the directions provided by the user guide for m2.

Essentially, you can use XML.  As long as your "page layout" is set to 2 columns you can utilize the  tag to move the top links bar to a destination of your choice.

**Note: you should create a custom theme for this as "editing" the base theme directly is not suggested.